# WKWebview snapshot configuration not supported in iOS 9

Tags: webview, wkwebview, snapshot, ios9.3, ios10.3.2

I m getting crash when I try to take snapshot of wkwebview in iOS 9.0,can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

_webView takeSnapshotWithConfiguration:wkSnapshotConfig completionHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable snapshotImage, NSError * _Nullable error)